# Phpmyadmin: The mysqli extension is missing

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed apache2 and php in /usr/local by compiling files.
I installed mysql and phpmyadmin by the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
```

Phpmyadmin is not running and this shows:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

But i installed php with `--mysqli`:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-maintainer-zts --with-mysqli
```

Comment: `-mysqli` doesn't match with `--with-mysql` in your configure command?

Comment: no, doesn't match.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the full error message.

Comment: the question was edited. please check again. thanks

Comment: Ok, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You just need to type this command which will enable your extension *mysqli* and then restart your apache2 server. This will help your server to work:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

With the command

```
./configure …
```

you have nothing installed. You have a source package configured, that's all.

To install and use the extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

---

But the easiest way is

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

as the package `php5-mysql` is a dependency of `phpmyadmin`

Finally restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: @Garme: type the above commands in a terminal...